# Can I add my own commands/scripts to the mail.app toolbar?

Tags: mail.app

Is there a way (or an add-on) that lets me customize the Mail.app toolbar beyond "View -> Customize Toolbar"? At a minimum, I want to add buttons that do "Move to <somefolder>".

Comment: I don't have an answer for you, but welcome, Paul!

Comment: I do not have an answer for this either. But I guess you can create tiny applescripts, and bind them to keyboard shortcuts.

Comment: Not really an answer to your question but maybe a workaround. You could use automator to add actions to the services menu

Comment: To be clear, I really really want something that creates buttons on the toolbar: I don't want to memorize any more keystrokes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read [CocoaDev: HowToAddButtonsToAppleMail](https://web.archive.org/web/20070814022303/http://cocoadev.com/index.pl?HowToAddButtonsToAppleMail).  It references a page of links to articles/examples on writing Mail.app plugins.  You will also need to do some [programming of Mail.app, e.g. using AppleScript - which you can learn more about here](http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20030116071118239).

Here is a year-and-a-half old [blog post by a guy who managed to get some useful control over Mail.app from AppleScript](http://www.kith.org/journals/jed/2009/09/12/12380.html).  You might use it as a model. He built his with a third-party module but you might find a way to write your own, if necessary.

The scripting of Mail.app might be stable.  However, from what I have read - the rules for how to construct a Mail.app plugin may be in flux from one major version of Mac OS X to the next.

That could be enough to discourage you from writing what you want for wide distribution but it might not be much of a handicap for personal use.

Comment: That does discourage me, yes. :-) However, it is the best we have seen, and it is probably the definitive answer, unfortunately.

Answer (score 3):

I think you can use Mail Act-on for this, it provides Shortcuts for doing stuff with various mails. Not a Visual Shortcut, but a Keyboard one.

> Move messages by keystroke only Mail
>   Act-On’s interface includes the
>   ability to move or copy messages to
>   any folders by keystroke, even if you
>   don’t have an Act-On rule for a
>   particular mailbox.

http://www.indev.ca/MailActOn.html

Hope it helps,

Karl

Comment: Thanks, but I really want something visual. I have way too many keyboard shortcuts to remember as it is. FWIW, I use MsgFiler now, and it seems less intrusive than Act-On.

Answer (score 2):

1. Open Automator
2. File -> New -> Service -> Choose
3. Service receive `no input` in `Mail.app`
4. From library select Utilities -> Run AppleScript
5. Insert the code provided below and save under name `Move to trash [Gmail]` [image]
6. Edit the script and change your account name. Name of the account could be found at Mail -> Preferences... -> Accounts
7. Open Mail.app and select Mail -> Services -> Service Preferences...
8. Assign a shortcut to the service `Move to trash [Gmail]`
9. Restart Mail.app
10. (Optional) You should be able to see the assigned shortcut in the menu [image]
11. Open inbox, select messages to be moved to trash and press the keyboard shortcut*. Messages will be moved to [Gmail]/Trash

***Note:** For the first time the script works quite long, but all the following times it should proceed much faster.

AppleScript:

```
on run {input, parameters}
    tell application "Mail"
        set s to selection
        repeat with i from 1 to the count of s
            set msg to item i of s
            set box to mailbox of msg
            if name of box is not "[Gmail]/Trash" then
                move msg to mailbox "[Gmail]/Trash" of account "<Your account name here>"
            end if
        end repeat
    end tell
end run
```

This approach does not allow to add a button to the toolbar, but it's very close to what you are looking for.

Useful links:

- https://support.google.com/mail/answer/78892?hl=en
- http://support.apple.com/kb/PH11788