# how to make an "archive" button for Mail.app in mac os x mountain lion to work with gmail accounts?

Tags: macos, mail.app, gmail, archive

has anyone tried to build an "archive" button for apple mail to move mails from the `Inbox` to `All Mail` in `Mail.app` (Mountain lion)?

there is this page: http://stl.techinno.nl/archive/
but it wont work with the mail version on mountain lion.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You could [assign a shortcut to a script](https://superuser.com/questions/153890/assign-a-shortcut-to-running-a-script-in-os-x/264943#264943) like this:

```
tell application "Mail" to tell account "Gmail"
    messages of mailbox "INBOX" whose flagged status is false and read status is true
    move result to mailbox "[Gmail]/All Mail"
end tell
```

This would only move selected messages:

```
tell application "Mail"
    selected messages of message viewer 1
    move result to mailbox "[Gmail]/All Mail" of account "Gmail"
end tell
```

Comment: ok, the second script worked very well...

Comment: how can I add it to the tool bar of mail?

Comment: I don't know, but there is [another question about adding scripts to the toolbar](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/10384/can-i-add-my-own-commands-scripts-to-the-mail-app-toolbar). If you don't want to use a shortcut, you could also run the script with Alfred or Launchbar.